# NoMethodError: undefined method `has_attached_file'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3

Paperclip produces this error, after checking out the plugin's rails3 branch. 
My Gemfile has following line:

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => 'http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

And the error message is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<Class:0x2a50530>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update 06-21-10:** the [thoughtbot](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) version has been fixed.

I had to add `Paperclip::Railtie.insert` to my application.rb at the end of `class Application < Rails::Application` to get it to work correctly. I have deleted my fork since the official repo is working. Hope that helps someone.

You will also need to add the following to your Gemfile

```
gem "paperclip", :git => "http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a paperclip fork, you can try if it will work at your end, just change your Gemfile:

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => 'git://github.com/lmumar/paperclip.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

Don't forget to run bundle install after updating your Gemfile.

Hope it will fix your problems.

lmumar

Comment: "There was a LoadError while evaluating paperclip.gemspec.
Does it try to require a relative path? That doesn't work in Ruby 1.9."

Comment: Thanks - working for me :-)
This will keep me going until the master gets fixed fully for Rails3.

Comment: This fork worked for me as well. Hopefully thoughtbot will pull from lmumar soon :)

Answer (score 2):

That didn't work for me.
I have done below things and it is working perfectly:

- Add "Paperclip::Railtie.insert" in application.rb
- Add "config.gem 'paperclip'" in development.rb

Answer (score 1):

minter's fork worked for me:

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => 'http://github.com/minter/paperclip.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

Answer (score -1):

it works with Jason King's paperclip version:

```
gem 'paperclip', :git => 'http://github.com/JasonKing/paperclip.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to exist any more.